# Get Index of Max Value by Category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of operations data. I need to return a record for each `Vendor` with their corresponding maximum `Insert Date`.

```
#import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_clipboard() 

Vendor  Insert_Date Total 
Steph   2017-10-25  2
Matt    2017-10-31  13
Chris   2017-11-03  3
Steve   2017-10-23  11
Chris   2017-10-27  3
Steve   2017-11-01  11
```

I would like to return the following result (order does not matter unless it impacts index):

```
Vendor  Insert_Date Total 
Steph   2017-10-25  2
Steve   2017-11-01  11
Matt    2017-10-31  13
Chris   2017-11-03  3
```

I can retreive the max `Insert Date`s  for each `Vendor` by using `df.groupby(['Vendor']).agg({'Insert_Date':'max'})` But I would like to have the index so I can use `iloc` (or other form of `loc`) and filter the results. I've been playing with [`idxmax()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for a little bit, but can't seem to get the desired result

Comment: Show us the code you have been trying so far.

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal, I have many columns in my true dataset that this type of 'hard-coding' would not apply. Maybe should have made that more clear in my question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a good recommendation to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['Vendor','InsertDate']).drop_duplicates(['Vendor'],keep='last')
Out[1442]: 
  Vendor  InsertDate  Total
2  Chris  2017-11-03      3
1   Matt  2017-10-31     13
0  Steph  2017-10-25      2
5  Steve  2017-11-01     11
```

Comment: clever. I tried using sort values, but never thought of `drop_duplicates`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
df['Insert Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Insert Date'])
df.iloc[df.groupby('Vendor')['Insert Date'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
  Vendor Insert Date  Total
2  Chris  2017-11-03      3
1   Matt  2017-10-31     13
0  Steph  2017-10-25      2
5  Steve  2017-11-01     11
```

Comment: idxmax throws me errors when I try using it. Did you convert this to a datetime col first?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ah.. yes, I did.

Comment: ah, that is how to apply `idxmax`. I was at a loss for the correct application