# Get N Largest Date Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165083/get-index-of-max-value-by-category) and need to expand on the application. I now need to get the `N` max date for each `Vendor`:

```
#import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_clipboard()
#df['Insert_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Insert_Date'])

# used in example below 
#df2 = df.sort_values(['Vendor','InsertDate']).drop_duplicates(['Vendor'],keep='last') 

Vendor  Insert_Date Total 
Steph   2017-10-25  2
Matt    2017-10-31  13
Chris   2017-11-03  3
Steve   2017-10-23  11
Chris   2017-10-27  3
Steve   2017-11-01  11
```

If I needed to get the 2nd max date expected output would be:

```
Vendor  Insert_Date Total 
Steph   2017-10-25  2
Steve   2017-10-23  11
Matt    2017-10-31  13
Chris   2017-10-27  3
```

I can easily get the 2nd max date by using `df2` in the example `df.loc[~df.index.isin(df2.index)]` but if i need to get the 50th max value, that is a lot of dataframe building to use `isin()`...

I have also tried `df.groupby('Vendor')['Insert_Date'].nlargest(N_HERE)` which gets me close, but i then need to get the `N` value for each Vendor.

I have also tried filtering out the df by Vendor:

`df.loc[df['Vendor']=='Chris', 'Insert_Date'].nlargest(2)`

but if I try to get the second record with `df.loc[df['Vendor']=='Chris', 'Insert_Date'].nlargest(2)[2]` it returns: `Timestamp('2017-11-03 00:00:00')`. Instead i need to use `df.loc[df['Vendor']=='Chris', 'Insert_Date'].nlargest(2)[1:2]`. Why must I use list slicing here and not simply`[2]`?

In summary? how do I return the `N` largest date by Vendor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might've misunderstood your initial problem. You can sort on `Insert_Date`, and then use `groupby` + `apply` in this manner:

```
n = 9
df.sort_values('Insert_Date')\
          .groupby('Vendor', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-n])
```

For your example data, it seems `n = 0` does the trick.

```
df.sort_values('Insert_Date')\
      .groupby('Vendor', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0])

  Vendor Insert_Date  Total
0  Chris  2017-10-27      3
1   Matt  2017-10-31     13
2  Steph  2017-10-25      2
3  Steve  2017-10-23     11
```

Beware, this code will throw errors if your `Vendor` groups are smaller in size than `n`.

Comment: This works for this small example. But what if there were say 10 dates for each Vendor and I needed to get the 9th largest date?

Comment: @MattR Let me explain myself. I only assumed you had mistaken the order, and I tried to correct it. Anyway, I might have misunderstood your initial statement, but I've tried to correct that in an edit.

Comment: I tried something similar. I had NO idea you could use `iloc` in an `apply()`. Once again I feel like I try to reinvent the wheel and you guys just do it instantly.

Comment: @MattR Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm just trying to fix some kinks. I've shown you how to get the nth largest date in a general sense.

Answer (score 2):

I will using `head` (You can pick the top n here I am using 2) and always `drop_duplicates` by the last.

```
df.sort_values('Insert_Date',ascending=False).groupby('Vendor').\
     head(2).drop_duplicates('Vendor',keep='last').sort_index()
Out[609]: 
  Vendor Insert_Date  Total
0  Steph  2017-10-25      2
1   Matt  2017-10-31     13
3  Steve  2017-10-23     11
4  Chris  2017-10-27      3
```

Comment: gives the same answer! (except i think `df2` should be `df`?) again with the sorting magic. do you know why `head(N)` returns the entire dataframe?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.21.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L3250-L3265 you can check here, basically `head(n)==.iloc[:n,:]` I am using `head`, just do not want to involve `apply` .

Comment: i may be missing something in that comment. I apologize, but I cannot figure out why: `df.sort_values('Insert_Date',ascending=False).groupby('Vendor').head(2)` returns the entire dataframe?

Comment: @MattR after groupby , each subdf size is less than 2 , so when you doing it head(2) will return the whole subset back then you will see the entire df returned. You can think about ,` head` is just like the `sum` , they apply to each subset

Comment: @MattR yw~ :-) have nice day

Answer (score 1):

I like @COLDSPEED's answer as its more direct. Here is one using nlargest which involves an intermediate step of creating nthlargest column

```
n = 2
df1['nth_largest'] = df1.groupby('Vendor').Insert_Date.transform(lambda x: x.nlargest(n).min())
df1.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Vendor', 'nth_largest']).drop('Insert_Date', axis = 1)


    Vendor  Total   nth_largest
0   Steph   2   2017-10-25
1   Matt    13  2017-10-31
2   Chris   3   2017-10-27
3   Steve   11  2017-10-23
```